# LEFT JOIN CTE as Lambda Expression / Query Expression

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lambda

How do I write this following SQL query (CTE LEFT JOINED with another table) as a Lambda or Query Expression?

```sql
WITH Hours as
(
    SELECT 0 As Hour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Hour + 1
    FROM Hours
    WHERE Hour + 1 < 24
)
SELECT Hours.Hour, COALESCE(Revenue, 0) FROM Hours 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT DATEPART(hh, TableDate) As Hour, SUM(Revenue) Revenue FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, TableDate)
) c
ON 
c.Hour = Hours.Hour
```

I know I can GroupJoin and SelectMany to accomplish the LEFT JOIN, but I don't know where to start on representing the CTE portion of the query.  Will I have to just create a static table to accomplish this with a lambda or query expression?

-- edit --

So I finally ended up with this (preferred the query expression to lambda for readability):

```
    var revenue = (
                   from range in Enumerable.Range(0, 23)
                   join conv in db.MyTable on range equals conv.TableDate.Hour into c
                   from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group d by range into g
                   select new { Hour = g.Key, Revenue = g.Sum(e => e == null ? 0.0 : e.Revenue), }
                  )
```

Comment: I would rather be worried about common table expression (the `WITH` part). But anyway, have you already tried anything and can share any code you've written?

Comment: I should have edited my question to be more specific.  The CTE is exactly the part of the query where I'm having difficulty.  In fact, I don't know where to start.  I know I can accomplish a LEFT JOIN with a GroupJoin followed by a SelectMany on the derived Hour columns.  But I don't know how to specify the CTE.  Am I just going to have to create a static table in place of the CTE?

Comment: See my answer Jeff you use range to generate numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what your model would be in linq but probably something like this:

```
var Enumerable.Range(0,23)
      .Join(MyTable.GroupBy(x => x.TableDate.Hour())
             .Select(g => new { hour = g.Key, rev = g.Revenue.Sum() },
            h => h,
            g => g.hour,
            (h , g) -> new { hour = h, revenue = g.rev });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will not generate CTE SQL, but I think it might work! Really nice answer!

Comment: I never thought of using an Enumerable.Range.  I'll try that now.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Why would I want it to generate a CTE?

Comment: @Jeff - this is what the CTE is doing... creating a table (which is the same as an enumerable in linq) with the values 0 to 23.

Comment: @Hogan Source SQL from the question uses CTE :) But as long as it returns the same results, it's great!

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent linq query expression

```cs
from a in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
join b in Mytables on a equals b.TableDate.Hour into c
from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
group d by a into g
select new {h = g.Key, s = g.Sum(e => e == null ? 0.0m : e.Revenue)}
```

Comment: Thanks - I neded up using this for readability.  Only the Enumerable Range needed was only (0, 23) since there would be no TableDate.Hour that would translate to 24.

Comment: @Jeff The second argument to `Enumerable.Range` is the count, not the end point. You want 24.